# Concurrent access of a resource object by different threads within a certain order

Tags: java

Let's say I have a GameServer object which contains the data of a card game. 4 clients would access that object's functionality/data using Java RMI, and each of them are going to modify the game state in their own turn. After each player does a move, the others should be able to check the new state of the Game object. Being a card game, they also must follow a certain order of who should play at a certain time.

My first guess would be implement that using ReentrantLock + Condition, but I don't know how to manually assign which player should acquire the lock after the previous one release it.

Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: So you're wanting to make sure that only the player whose turn it is can modify the state?

Comment: this is not fundamentally a concurrency issue, it is a state machine issue.

Answer (score -1):

On the server, you have some sort of game state that each player can modify only on her turn. Let's call this state variable `gs`; it doesn't matter what type it is.

The most practical way of handling the in-order behavior is for the `gs` class to have a field representing whose turn it is (`int nextPlayer`). Your server RMI method that accepts take-my-turn commands from the players will check the `nextPlayer` field and ensure that it's the sending player's turn and return an error if not (perhaps `IllegalStateException`). The RMI take-my-turn method and the reading methods should be `synchronized(gs)`, since you need to make sure that the game state is updated atomically (including whose turn is next), and you won't be having much contention with four players.

Answer (score -2):

List of semaphores, one for each thread?

Each thread/player waits on its own semaphore in the list.  When it gets a unit, it 'plays', then signals the semaphore of the next thread/player along and loop around to wait on its own semaphore again.  If a player folds, or whatever, its thread can safely remove itself from the list before throwing the unit back into the semaphores.

At startup, throw in one unit to the first player to deal/whatever.

That solves mutual exclusion and play-order in one design.

It will work.

It's not messy.